# How to replicate two different database systems?

Tags: mysql, replication, mongodb

I'm not sure, if it fits exactly stackoverflow, however as i'm seeking for some code rather than a tool, i think it does.

I'm looking for a way of how to replicate / synchronize different database systems -- in this case: mysql and mongodb. We are running both for different purpose. We started with a mysql database and added mongodb later on for special applications. There's data we would like to have in both databases, where we want to have constraints in mysql respectivly dbrefs in mongodb. For example: We need a user-record in mysql, but also in mongodb for references between tables respectivly objects. At the moment we have a cronjob, which dumps the mysql data and imports it in mongodb. However though it works quite well, that's not the solution we would like to have.

I think for the moment a one-way replication would be enough -- mysql->mongodb, the important part is, that the replication works in "realtime", much like a mysql master->slave replication works.

Are there already any solutions for this problem or ideas anyone of how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called EAI ([Enterprise application integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration)). There are a lot of commercial tools around but under the provided link, you'll also find a couple OSS solutions. The basis of EAI is that you have data sources and data sinks. The EAI framework offers tools to build custom pumps between the two.

I suggest to either use a DB trigger to start the synchronization or send a trigger signal in your applications. Note that there is no key-hole solution since synchronization can become arbitrarily complex (for example, how do you make sure that all rows are copied?).

Comment: What EAI that currently supports migrating from RDBMS to Schemaless database?

Answer (score 3):

[SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.org) is open source, Java-based, web-enabled, database independent, data synchronization/replication software that might do the trick with a few tweaks.  It has an extension point called IDataLoaderFilter which you could use to implement a MongodbDataLoader.

This would help with one way database replication.  It might be a little more difficult to synchronized from MongoDb -> relational database, but the SymmetricDS team would be very helpful in trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you need to develop some sort of "Control program" that has the drivers for each DBMS and run it as a daemon. The daemon should have a trigger or a very small recheck interval to keep the DBs synchronized

Comment: perhaps a trigger in the DBMS itself could cascade the change?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could set up a process which parses the binary log of the MySQL server and replicate the relevant sql queries. I've never done such a thing with a a different database as a slave, but maybe it is worth a shot?